# Problem with PeriodicWorkRequests using WorkManager, in android

Tags: java, android

I have implemented periodic work request to update the weather and show the notification after a fixed period of time. But, it is not working properly. One day the notifications are shown after fixed intervals but another day the notifications do not appear at all unless I open the app.
Can anybody explain the possible reason for this bug?

Comment: What's your test device? Do you have the same problem with your Samsung or Pixel phone? in Huawei and Xiaomi devices OS kill background tasks, we have the same issue with notification.

Comment: WorkRequests are not exact, and depend on the mysterious and undocumented "battery life" rating.  Have you tried tracing logs to see the status of the Work? whether it's enqueued or not?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am using a Samsung Phone.